# RADOS permission denied

Tags: ceph

I'm trying to install a ceph cluster using 3 ubuntu 20.04 machine each with 4 disk.
I've followed the manual installation from here https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/install/manual-deployment/#monitor-bootstrapping
At the last step I have the service running but if I use `sudo ceph -s` the terminal does not responds, if I use without sudo I get the RADOS permission denied.

Also tried with ceph-deploy and (for test) in a single node environment.
and I get the same error when using: `ceph-deploy osd create --data /dev/sdX <osd-node>`

Tried to create manually the keyring with ceph-authtool following some guides but nothing seems fine to solve the problem.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add more details? Which service do you have running? There's plenty of information missing here, besides the fact that `ceph-deploy` is deprecated. I recommend to use `cephadm` instead as it's the default since ceph octopus. Can you share `ls -l /etc/ceph/` and also the log file (`/var/log/ceph/ceph-mon.{hostname}.log`) of the monitor service, it should reveal if it's actually running. I've been following the manual deployment quite often, it usually worked for me. Did you get any errors during the manual deployment?